# Can an open type be a struct?

Tags: c#, generics, struct

I have some types that are structs for performance reasons and have some commonality.  I would like to know if I can refactor them to be open type structs -- and if I should expect any problems if I can.

Comment: What is an "open type struct" in the first place?

Comment: correct -- generic open type.  i.e. can public class Box<T> be public struct Box<T>?

Comment: What happens when you type `public struct Box<T>` into VS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. Some of the generic types provided by the framework library, such as [`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx), are indeed `structs`.

Comment: Thanks -- I had not realized this and that helps.

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: Apparently by "open type" you do not mean the same thing as the C# specification definition of "open type". You mean "generic type".

Yes, structs can be generic.

To answer the second part of your question: I don't know what sorts of "problems" you have in mind. Can you give me an example of something you find problematic?

---

Original answer, assuming that you were actually asking about open types:

The C# specification is clear on this point:

> • A
>   type parameter defines an open type.
>
> • An array type is an open type if and
>   only if its element type is an open
>   type.
>
> • A constructed type is an open
>   type if and only if one or more of its
>   type arguments is an open type. A
>   constructed nested type is an open
>   type if and only if one or more of its
>   type arguments or the type arguments
>   of its containing type(s) is an open
>   type.

So there you go. A struct type is an open type if and only if it, or its enclosing type, is a generic type with an open type for one of its type arguments. For example:

```
struct S<T>
{
  S<T> s1; // open struct type
  Nullable<S<T>> s2; // another open struct type
}

class O<V>
{
  class C<U> where U : struct
  {
    struct R
    {
      U u; // open type constrained to be value type
      R r1; // open struct type; this is O<V>.C<U>.R
      O<V>.C<S<U>>.R r2; // another open struct type.
      O<int>.C<S<V>>.R r3; // another open struct type 
    }
  }
}
```

We can keep on making open struct types all day.

Comment: Thanks for the information -- was really helpful.  The "problems" I was asking about was if I should expect some limitation by using structs in an open generic type that would dissuade one from doing so.  Seems like there are framework types that do this and maybe have similarity in approach for solving what I wanted.